# getting timeout error when select the 50th page in telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

I am loading 100000 records in the Radgrid, if I am doing anything (select 50th page in RadGrid Pager Control or Filter something in the RadGrid) in the radgrid it's taking too much of time to load, sometimes I got the error like "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.",

This is the code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridRollup" Skin="Vista" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"

ShowHeader="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="false"

PageSize="50" OnNeedDataSource="RadGridRollup_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="true"

EnableLinqExpressions="false" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" PagerStyle-Position="Bottom"

GridLines="None" Height="300px" Width="1000px" >

<ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true" EnableRowHoverStyle="true">

<Scrolling AllowScroll="True" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="True" UseStaticHeaders="True"

SaveScrollPosition="True" />

</ClientSettings>

<GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />

<MasterTableView PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" PagerStyle-Position="Bottom" PagerStyle-Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric">

<ItemStyle Wrap="true" />

<Columns>

</Columns>

</MasterTableView>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

After that I include the properties (ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false" for RadGrid) at that time also I am having same error.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do further to improve the performance?